# Creating PowerBI Dax Measure

Tags: powerbi, dax

https://i.stack.imgur.com/DqpGL.png

Hi all, for any given part # I am trying to create a measure that will multiply the total value by the on-hands values if the actual location and MFG location are equal. The image shown is one part # that is all the same, however, this will not always be the case as there are multiple different part #s. In theory, all of the entries to create the on-hand $ will be the on-hands multiplied by the 1.34 value since that is where the actual location and MFG location match.

Wrote PowerBI measures that did not give the output I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

It helps a LOT if you post what you tried. =)

This is a case for SUMX, because you need to evaluate [On-Hands * [Total] first, and then sum that result... and SUM can't "look sideways" (doesn't manufacture a row context like an iterator does).

```
SUMX('FactTableName',
IF([Actual Location]=[MFG Location],
   [On-Hands]*[Total],
   FALSE CASE)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

→ If you want measure, it would be:

```
On hand$ = 
CALCULATE(SELECTEDVALUE('Table'[Total]),
    'Table'[Actual Location]='Table'[MFG Location],
    ALLEXCEPT('Table','Table'[Part #])
    )
*
SUM('Table'[On-hands])
```

→ If you want column, it would be:

```
On hand $ = 
CALCULATE(SELECTEDVALUE('Table'[Total]),
    'Table'[Actual Location]='Table'[MFG Location],
    ALLEXCEPT('Table','Table'[Part #])
    )
*
[On-hands]
```

Results are same.

[image]